# How to disable swipe gesture of UINavigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

In App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    WalkThrough  *viewControllers=[[WalkThrough alloc]init];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllers];



[self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: your coding is fine , what the problem u faced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable interactivePopGestureRecognizer ***after*** `[window makeKeyAndVisible]`.

The key to the problem is that `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` property is `nil` until ***both*** two conditions are met:

1. the navigationController is associated to the window
2. the window become key and visible